# Distributed Geodatabase ExportDataChangeMessage

Tags: arcobjects, spatial-database

How to perform ExportDataChangeMessage. I am not getting where to get in_replica.
My code is:

```
Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();
GP.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", outputpath1);
GP.OverwriteOutput = true;
ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.ExportDataChangeMessage exportdataChange = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.ExportDataChangeMessage();
exportdataChange.in_geodatabase = pathofrelicated mdb file;

exportdataChange.in_replica = "SubJob_309227531_Jp";
exportdataChange.out_data_changes_file = any  mdb;
exportdataChange.switch_to_receiver = "SWITCH";
exportdataChange.include_unacknowledged_changes = "UNACKNOWLEDGED";
exportdataChange.include_new_changes = "NEW_CHANGES";
GP.Execute(exportdataChange, null);
```

giving me error

ERROR 000286: An error was encountered while executing ExportReplicaSchema.

Comment: What error? Are there any error codes or messages that might identify the likely cause? Does ExportDataChangeMessage geoprocessing tool from ArcCatalog toolbox work with the given parameters? Which version of ArcGis/SDE and database are you using? Are you using correct credentials with your SDE connection?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution i was not getting the correct replica name while exporting the data change 
here is my complete code:- >

```
  String filename="E:\Osgb Project\Test\SubJob_3089559_10_R10\GPMS_308955910_Extract.mdb"  
                IGeoDataServer geoDataServer = new GeoDataServerClass();  
                IGeoDataServerInit geoDataServerInit = (IGeoDataServerInit)geoDataServer;    
                geoDataServerInit.InitFromFile(filename);
                String currentReplicaName=string.Empty;  
                IGPReplicas gpReplicas = geoDataServer.Replicas;  
                for (int i = 0; i < gpReplicas.Count; i++)
                {  
                    IGPReplica currentReplica = gpReplicas.get_Element(i);  
                    currentReplicaName = currentReplica.Name;  
                }    

                string dd = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
                string filenameWIthExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
                string dirctory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
                string outPutFileName = filenameWIthExtension + "_Delta.mdb";
                string outputpath1 = dirctory;
                string outputpath = dirctory + "\\" + outPutFileName;
                Geoprocessor GP = new Geoprocessor();
                GP.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", outputpath1);
                GP.OverwriteOutput = true;
                GP.RegisterGeoProcessorEvents(gpEventHandler);
                ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.ExportDataChangeMessage exportdataChange = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.ExportDataChangeMessage();
                exportdataChange.in_geodatabase = filename;
                exportdataChange.in_replica = currentReplicaName;
                exportdataChange.out_data_changes_file = outputpath;
                exportdataChange.switch_to_receiver = "SWITCH";
                exportdataChange.include_unacknowledged_changes = "UNACKNOWLEDGED";
                exportdataChange.include_new_changes = "NEW_CHANGES";
                IGeoProcessorResult2 result;
                result = (IGeoProcessorResult2)GP.Execute(exportdataChange, null);
                while (result.Status != esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Status.ToString());
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                // If the job succeeded, retrieve the feature result. 
                if (result.Status == esriJobStatus.esriJobSucceeded)
                {
                  int i=  result.MessageCount;
                  MessageBox.Show("Completed Successfully..");
                }
                if (result.Status == esriJobStatus.esriJobFailed)
                {
                    string ss = result.Status.ToString();
                }
```